# Looking into a module calling the original module

Tags: ruby, module

How can I let a module to be included by another module look for a constant inside the including module? In other words, how can I make `B.foo` and `D.foo` below give the expected results?

```
module A
    module_function
    public
    def foo; C end
end
module B
    extend A
    C = "foo in B"
end
module D
    extend A
    C = "foo in D"
end

B.foo #=> (Expected) "foo in B"
D.foo #=> (Expected) "foo in D"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell it to lookup `C` in the context of where `A` is `extend`ed in:

```
module A
  def foo
    self::C
  end
end

module B
  extend A
  C = "foo in B"
end

module D
  extend A
  C = "foo in D"
end

B.foo #=> "foo in B"
D.foo #=> "foo in D"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain why `module_function` was unnecessary?

Comment: @sawa, because when you call [`Object#extend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-extend), you are adding the instance methods of the modules passed as argument to the receiver. If the receiver is a `Module` object, its instance methods are actually the "class methods". `module_function` makes it so the methods are defined as instance methods on the module's singleton class (metaclass) instead.

Comment: @sawa As far as I can tell, `module_function` only changes the behavior if you plan on redefining `A.foo` at some point. And also only possible when the module is being mixed-in to a class, not another module. Though I'm not 100% sure, as I don't have any prior experience with using it and the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_module.html#Module.module_function) aren't particularly enlightening. (@MatheusMoreira replied first, and I'll defer to him)

Comment: More details. Consider: `o = Object.new; def o.foo`. Only `o` will `respond_to? :foo`. Now, consider the Ruby idiom: `class A; def self.foo`. `self` is actually `A`, so this can be rewritten as `class A; end; def A.foo`. These are not just similar, _they are exactly the same_. All objects have a _singleton class_ which hold the _singleton methods_ only they respond to, and this applies to `Class` and `Module` objects. And since the singleton class is also an object...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend creating an attribute initializer that may be used by the other modules:

```
module A
  # This is actually executed in the context of each individual object.
  # Since all modules and classes are also objects, each module extended
  # by A gets to set its own state which the other methods can then use.
  def attribute(*args)
    @value = args.first if args.any?
    @value || :default
  end

  def foo
    attribute.to_s
  end
end

module B
  extend A
  attribute :from_B
end

module C
  extend A
  attribute :from_C
end

module D
  extend A
end

B.foo  # => "from_B"
C.foo  # => "from_C"
D.foo  # => "default"
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe yours will work, but the required coding seems to depart from what I wanted.

Comment: +1 because this is still good even if its not what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with constants, because they aren't inherited, but you can with methods:

```
module A
  def foo
    c
  end
end

module B
  extend A
  def self.c
     "foo in B"
  end
end

module D
  extend A
  def self.c
    "foo in D"
  end
end

B.foo #=> "foo in B"
D.foo #=> "foo in D"
```

Comment: Inherit isn't really the right word to use when talking about modules.

Comment: @Andrew - Sure it is. Including modules modifies the chain of ancestors.